Finding the real and imaginary part $ \frac {i}{\bar{z} +1} $
$ \frac {i}{\bar{z} +1} = \frac{i}{x-iy +1}$
Multiplying by $z$ gives:
$ \frac {zi}{{z^2} +z}$
$ \frac {ix -y}{x^2 + y^2 + x +iy}$
But how do I now get the im. part? By all multiplications I stil have an $i$ in de denominator.
Any help appreciated.

Don't multiply top and bottom by $z$, multiply by the conjugate of the denominator $\overline{z} + 1$, which is $z + 1$.

Note that if $a,b$ are complex with $b \neq 0$ then ${a \over b} = {a \bar{b} \over |b|^2}$.

$\bar z$ multiplied by $z$ is not $z^2$.

Instead:
$$\frac{i}{\overline{z}+1} = \frac{i}{\overline{z}+1} \times \frac{z+1}{z+1}.$$
If $z=x+iy$, notice that $z+\overline{z} = 2x$.  Hence,
$$\frac{i}{\overline{z}+1} = \frac{i(z+1)}{|z|^2+z+\overline{z}+1} = \frac{-y+(1+x)i}{x^2+y^2+2x+1}.$$
